# How to allow app access to images outside the app.asar file (in Electron App)?

Tags: electron

The [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) app I'm building bundles the resources into directory file "win-unpacked/resources/app.asar".

In the app itself, I allow users to custom write in paths to image files. For example, "image/my-own-img.png".

This works fine to add  in the app and allow the user to change the src to "image/my-own-image.png" to display that one instead.

However, the goal is to allow users to add their own images to the relative "images" folder, which would unfortunately be inside of the app.asar file. I've attempted to allow access outside this path, but I run into security issues and frankly have not been able to get that to work.

Aside from disabling asar, is there a way I could allow users to:
a) Install the app
b) Copy/paste their images into an images folder in the apps installed path *somewhere*
c) Have the app display that image when the relative path is typed in?

Thank you.

Comment: What packaging tool are you using now?

Comment: Hey, using this one: https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder